# Beginner Coding challenge - return first/last new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

I've been trying to crack this beginner question but I keep getting the answer 'undefined' and it is really puzzling me.....

All help gratefully received!!

```js
function firstLast(array) {
  var first = array[0];
  var last = array[array.length - 1];

  var newArray = [];
  newArray.push(first, last)
  return newArray;
}

console.log(firstLast[2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: To call the function you need to use `()`, so `firstLast([2, 3, 4, 5])`

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, no. push takes as many as you want ... (nearly)

Answer (score 1):

You need some braces around the array to call the function.

By using square brackets, you take the content as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) of an object.

```js
function firstLast(array) {
  var first = array[0];
  var last = array[array.length - 1];

  var newArray = [];
  newArray.push(first, last)
  return newArray;
}

console.log(firstLast([5]));
//                   ^            ^
```

A function is a callable object with properties, but the handed over structure is now not an array, but a property accessor with brackets and some numbers with a
[comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). This are some expressions separated with comma and the last value is taken as key for the object.

If you add this property to the function, you get a value.

```js
function firstLast(array) {
  var first = array[0];
  var last = array[array.length - 1];

  var newArray = [];
  newArray.push(first, last)
  return newArray;
}

firstLast[5] = 'surprise!'

console.log(firstLast[2, 3, 4, 5]); // without braces
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks!! It now works

Answer (score 1):

It took me some little time but I noticed that you have a syntax error:

`console.log(firstLast[2,3,4,5]);`

Notice the `firstLast[2,3,4,5]` should be `firstLast([2,3,4,5])`

As @Nina Scholz said, square brackets `[]` are property accessor of an object. And `firstLast` is a function, not an object.